# How do I let the user name the output.txt file in my C program?

Tags: c, file

How to I give the user the ability to name the output .txt file? Here is all I have right now.

```
FILE *f = fopen("output.txt", "a");
```

Comment: Do you have a GUI or command line?

Comment: `scanf` a string using `%s` and use it as the first argument of `fopen`.

Comment: `"output.txt"` is a string - learn/google how to store and modify a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the input from user and append `.txt`

```
char fileName[30];
// ...
scanf("%25s", fileName); // max 25 characters because .txt have 4 (25+4 = 29)
strcat(fileName, ".txt"); // append .txt extension
// ...
FILE *f = fopen(fileName, "a");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array argv :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc == 2) {
        FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "a");      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then when you compile and execute the code : ./foo output.txt

Answer (score 0):

In the function `fopen` the first argument is the name for te file, now your are using a constant but you can use a variable(a string). You could take it from `scanf` or via `argv` or via `GUI`